# PostgreSQL throws "Connection has been abandoned" -> "An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I know that there are a lot of topics about abandoned connections , however I can't figure out what is the problem in my case, so I really hope for some help.

I have a Java application with Spring, which fetches some data from external services, and tries to save it in database.

I have the following configuration for JDBC pool

```
<bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
          p:initialSize="2"
          p:minIdle="10"
          p:maxIdle="50"
          p:maxActive="100"
          p:maxWait="15000"
          p:jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer"
          p:removeAbandoned="true"
          p:removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          p:logAbandoned="true"
          p:testOnBorrow="true"
          p:testOnReturn="true"
          p:testWhileIdle="true"
          p:useEquals="false"
          p:fairQueue="false"
          p:timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000"
          p:minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="300000"
          p:validationInterval="10000"
          p:validationQuery="SELECT 1">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
```

It's a typical Spring env, and in my service I have got a following method

```
@Autowired
private TransactionalWrapper wrapper;

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void reconcileAllEvents(Date from, Date to) {
   for (Event event : eventService.reconcile(from, to)) {   
            transactionalWrapper.reconcile(event);   
   }    
}
```

And here is what I have in `TransactionalWrapper`

```
@Service
public class TransactionalWrapperImpl implements TransactionalWrapper {

        @Autowired
        private EventRepository eventRepository;

        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public void reconcile(Event event) {

            try {
                eventRepository.save(event);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.warn("Failed to handle event {}", event, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a nightly job running and every time there are about ~10K events. I have checked that in `reconcileAllEvents()` there is no active transaction, and in `TransactionalWrapperImpl.reconcile()` new transaction is created and committed for each `event`.

The problem is that from time to time I am getting following exceptions

```
Sep 10, 2015 5:25:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool abandon
WARNING: Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection[org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@3eb948ed]:java.lang.Exception
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getThreadDump(ConnectionPool.java:1063)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:780)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:619)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1351)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:110)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
```

And after this one there is another one

```
10 Sep 2015 17:25:57,591 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
10 Sep 2015 17:25:57,592 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:316)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractJPAQuery.java:219)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractJPAQuery.java:295)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractJPAQuery.java:281)
    at com.mysema.query.support.ProjectableQuery.singleResult(ProjectableQuery.java:75)
```

I checked the configuration several times, and can't find anything wrong or what needs to be approved, and this keeps crashing and the events are not being saved. Note that after exception it continues to save the rest of the events in a normal way.

Any ideas what is wrong in configuration, and how it is possible to handle the issue?

Comment: What does your `eventService.reconcile` look like. Looks like processing takes too long and the connection is considered idle/abandoned.

Comment: ```eventService.reconcile(from, to)``` does not have any iteraction with database... It is just reconciling the status of the event with external provider via API... So I assume there shouldn't be any connection at all , or?

Comment: Then why bother with a `@Transactional` at all. Exception occurs on retrieving an object from the database. The code you show doesn't do that, so there must be something doing a query to the database.

Comment: Another thing is that you shouldn't catch exceptions as that will break proper tx management.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is usually thrown by PostgreSQL when the connection is dropped on the back-end side.

1. Try updating the driver to the latest version: [9.4-1202](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/)
2. In `postgresql.conf` try setting: [`log_statement = 'all'`](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-multi-row-insert-rewritebatchedinserts-property/), to see all statement log data, so you can better understand what's causing the issue.

Comment: I have changed the driver to latest version it didn't help unfortunately. Though enabling the logs for postgre is a nice idea, will try to dig deeper!

Comment: So there was indeed a query who was causing the problem! Thanks a lot for a hint to enable logs in postgre.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is because your outer method is using transaction propagation NOT_SUPPORTED. This configuration will pause other opened transactions, and as a large amount of data is processed, timeouts could happen on those paused transactions.

I known You said that this method is executed when there are not active transactions, but are you completely sure? The single result error suggests there is a select statement being executed.

You could try another propagation configuration that suits your requirements and see if it works.